# What's wrong with query error in Laravel with XAMPP on Mac?

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

I am a beginner programmer and use Laravel with XAMPP on Mac. And all my attempts to create migrations lead to Query Error:

Illuminate\Database\QueryException

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel-app and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

My PHP version is 7.3.29 on MacBook

In XAMPP web-server: Apache/2.4.48 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1k PHP/8.0.10 mod_perl/2.0.11 Perl/v5.32.1

What steps should i take to customize the request?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Laravel issue, but a general MySQL Issue. Maybe the server is not running. Are you sure you're running MySQL in the background?

Check this link: [MySQL Gone Away](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/gone-away.html)

Do the following checks in your system:

1. The Database Engine is running
2. You have created your database
3. You have created an user and granted permissions to the database
4. You have setup the user and the database in your Laravel's .env file.

After this, try to run the migrations command again, which is:

```
php artisan migrate
```

As explained [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations#running-migrations)